# In R graphics, what is the different between plotting characters (pch) 16 and 19?

Tags: r

I can't find any documentation other than mentions of "filled" vs "solid".

```
library(graphics)
plot.new()
points(.48, .5, pch=19)
points(.52, .5, pch=16)
```

[image]

**Edit:** Winston Chang's explanation answeres my question pretty thoroughly https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1757#issuecomment-247804365

Comment: seems one has a border or something like one ... `points(0.25, .5, pch=19, cex=20, col=scales::alpha("red", 0.5), lwd=8) ; 
points(0.75, .5, pch=16, cex=20, col=scales::alpha("red", 0.5), lwd=8)`

Comment: Maybe this is clearer..compare  `points(0.5, .5, pch=19, cex=20, col=scales::alpha("red", 0.5), lwd=20) ; 
points(0.5, .5, pch=16, cex=20, col=scales::alpha("black", 0.5), lwd=20)` with `points(0.5, .5, pch=19, cex=20, col=scales::alpha("red", 0.5), lwd=0) ; 
points(0.5, .5, pch=16, cex=20, col=scales::alpha("black", 0.5), lwd=0)`

Comment: @sharoz You should make your edit an answer and accept it. I would have upvoted it!

Answer (score 4):

This may help:

Values of pch are stored internally as integers. The interpretation is

```
NA_integer_: no symbol.

0:18: S-compatible vector symbols.

19:25: further R vector symbols.

26:31: unused (and ignored).

32:127: ASCII characters.

128:255 native characters only in a single-byte locale and for the symbol font. (128:159 are only used on Windows.)

-32 ... Unicode code point (where supported).
```

The full text is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/points.html)

Comment: And what is the difference between an "S-compatible vector symbol" and a "further R vector symbol"?

Comment: This is is how I understand it but I may be wrong. R is based on the S language, so if writing R code to be used also with S use the S compatible pch, otherwise it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

I used your code, and saving the image as svg.

When opening in Inkscape, the different is that 19 has a "stroke", that is a border. 16 does not.

[image]

Note that this is not a separate shape, but within the same shape.

Answer (score 3):

From Hadley's new book [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#aesthetic-mappings): *Note that there are some seeming duplicates: 0, 15, and 22 are all squares. The difference comes from the interaction of the colour and fill aesthetics. The hollow shapes (0–14) have a border determined by colour; the solid shapes (15–18) are filled with colour; the filled shapes (21–24) have a border of colour and are filled with fill.*

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't explain the difference between 16 and 19

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. My understanding is that 15-18 (pch=15, filled square blue; pch=16, filled circle blue; pch=17, filled triangle point up blue
pch=18, filled diamond blue) are the basic shapes and 19 and 20 (pch=19,solid circle blue; pch=20,bullet (smaller circle) are additional shapes. On my machine 19 is slightly bigger than 16, so if you want uniformity of size use 15-18 or 21-25.